# Get Current Network player transform/gameobject in unet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

How can i get current network player transform object?
there is

> [Network.player](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network-player.html)

but it don't give me the transform or gameobject.
I am willing to get the transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get current networking player using this line of code:

```
 GameObject currentPlayer = FindObjectOfType<NetworkManager >().client.connection.playerControllers[0].gameObject;
```

**[NetworkManager.client](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager-client.html)**

The current NetworkClient being used by the manager.

This is populated when StartClient or StartLocalClient are called.

Answer (score 0):

`Network` is just a C# class and `Network.player` is a `static` instance of `NetworkPlayer` (a C# struct).  Neither implement `Component` and therefore don't have a `GameObject` or `Transform` that they're attached to.

Comment: Hey thanks but i amazed that you have over 5 reputation but still write a comment in answer section. anyway thanks for input

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan You're asking for a `Transform` or `GameObject` from something that has/represents neither.  The answer _is_ that you won't get either of those components from `Network.player`.